# C Programming: passing struct as a parameter - Function

Tags: c, struct, structure

I am trying Add a new ITEM to GI array, but this doesn't seem to work. 
I am hitting a brick wall here. Can anyone advise please?
I tried passing additem(GI, &Recs, 222) as shown below and updating values:

```
#include <stdio.h>


   struct Item {
   double value;
   int unitno;
   int isTa;
   int quant;
   int minQuan;
   char name[31];
};

struct Item GI[21] = {
   { 41.4,1275,01,110,12,"Apples" },
   { 52.99,3826,02,220,24,"Melon" },
};
int Recs=20;
void additem(struct Item item[], int *Recs, int unit);
void addtest();


int main ()
{
addtest();
return 0;
}

void addtest() {
additem(GI, &Recs, 222); 
}

void additem(struct Item item[], int *Recs, int value)
{
printf("--== Adding values! ==--\n");
        GI[21].value=44.44;
        GI[21].quant=44;
        GI[21].minQuan=4;
        strcpy(Recs->name, "vGrape");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out-of-bounds write, undefined behavior.

Comment: What is the size of your Item array? Try keeping a count of the number of spaces used in the array and use it to decide where new entries will be inserted.

Comment: @johnelemans I think I don't understand what you mean, insert into an array?

Comment: `strcpy(Recs->name, "vGrape");` : type of `Recs` is `int*`

Comment: additem is supposed to insert an new Item into the array which you called GI.

Comment: @EOF how to do proceed with it?

Comment: @johnelemans arrray's size is GI[21].

Comment: You need to back up and do some simpler things to learn how this works. Start with an array of 10 integers. Try changing values and printing out the array to see the results. Experiment with index values and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work. You can't dynamically add items to an array in c. You need dynamic memory allocation for that, namely [`malloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and family.

This is not a trivial matter, you can use `malloc()`'s sister `realloc()` to increase the size of a previously allocated portion of memory, but you should be careful not to do it too often because memory allocation is expensive in terms of computational time.

Comment: if I initialized array as GI[21] then I thought we reserved memory for that array?

Comment: As of now, I only have G[0] and G[1] full and rest of them are empty. May I know why I still need realloc?

Comment: You don't. It appears that you wanted more items than you initially allocated because you do `G[21]` which is beyond the array.

Answer (score 0):

Array of size 21 can take indexes 0 - 20 only.